# Memory Fault (CoreDump) - while using strstr function in sprintf

Tags: c, memory, coredump

I use strstr function to find String 1 in String 2 and assign the resultant to a variable using sprintf. However if there is no matching string found then am getting 'Memory Fault (Core Dump)' error when assigning a null pointer to the variable. Can help where i have missed the memory allocation. (Note : the same code works well when compiled in HP c but not with Solaris gcc compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char s1 [] = "My Car is Green";
char te [300];
sprintf(te,"%s",strstr (s1, "Car"));
printf("Result : %s\n",te);
te[0]='\0';
sprintf(te,"%s",strstr (s1, "Where"));
printf("Result : %s\n",te);
te[0]='\0';
}


Output:
Result : Car is Green
Memory fault(coredump)
```

Kindly help me on this?

Comment: `strstr (s1, "Where")` return `NULL`. Should not be expected to "NULL" is printed by printf.

Comment: And bear in mind that NULL is not the same as a zero length null terminated string... Reason why it might work on one platform and not another is due to the "undefined behaviour" associated with dereferencing NULL.

Comment: What did you expect to happen on that line?

Comment: Thanks guys, is there a way to assign a "NULL" to a variable using sprintf or other function.

Comment: @Irvan The best way is to not call strstr() inside the call to sprintf(). Call strstr() separately assigning the result to a pointer. Test the pointer to see if it is NULL, and only if it isn't should you then call sprintf() passing the pointer as the third argument.

Comment: or `sprintf(te,"%s",strstr (s1, "Where") ? : "(null)");` (GCC expansion). Also need `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY <(GCC expansion)> Tsk tsk!

Answer (score 1):

Passing NULL to sprintf can result into undefined behavior , even if you try to execute below program it will crash .

```
   int main ()

    {
      char buffer [50];
      int n, a=5, b=3;
     sprintf (buffer, "%s",(char*)NULL);

      return 0;
    }
```

Similarly , in your program `strstr (s1, "Where")` is returning NULL and this value will be passed to sprintf .

Comment: Thanks Sachin, Can advise how can it be tackled.,

Comment: @Irvan : Simply perform a NULL check before passing it to sprintf